# How to add zero to a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that receives a time, in a string, and another number to add to the time:

```
def get_hours(hm):
   return int(hm.split(':')[0])

def get_minutes(hm):
   return int(hm.split(':')[1])


def add_minutes(hm, incr):
"""Increment the given time by the given amount of minutes.

Requires:
- hm str with a time represented as HH:MM;
- incr int with the number of minutes.
Ensures: str with a time represented as HH:MM, the result of incrementing hm by incr minutes.
"""
if get_minutes(hm)+incr>=60:
    if get_hours(hm)==23:
        return '00:'+str((get_minutes(hm)+incr)-60)
    else:
        return str(get_hours(hm)+1)+':'+str((get_minutes(hm)+incr)-60)
else:
    return str(get_hours(hm))+':'+str((get_minutes(hm)+incr))
```

The problem is when the time is 16:05 or 04:06, it doesn't display the zeros, so it's just 16:5 and 4:6. How can i make this work?

Comment: You could use something like this: `timestamp = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: In general it’s better to use the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html) than to store the time as a string.

Comment: @StephenMiller Yes.. but you are missing the point here: there is no datetime or time library

Comment: @AntonvBR Yes there is. The OP isn’t using it, but it does exist, and there’s not a (specified) reason not to use it.

Comment: I agree.. but I didn't write to you.. Stephen propose time.strftime without explaining we need the import

Comment: Not only does the standard library have time parsing/printing functions, it also handles some edge cases better. What if `get_minutes(hm)+incr >= 120`? What if `incr` is negative?

Answer (score 2):

Python has a function on the string class that may help you here;

```
"3".zfill(2)  # this will output 03
"20".zfill(2)  # this will output 20
```

Simply cast your ints to a string, and call `.zfill(2)` prior to printing any results.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when working with time you want to use the built-in modules.

```
import time
time.strftime('%H:%M')
'00:23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be

```
"%.2i:%.2i" % (get_hours(hm), get_minutes(hm))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using the whole format string rather than just using it for parts? ie, `"%.2i:%.2i" % (get_hours(hm), get_minutes(hm))`?

Comment: Or even `f"{get_hours(hm):02d}:{get_minutes(hm):02d}"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you can work with datetime:

```
import datetime

def add_minutes(t, incr):
    return t + datetime.timedelta(minutes=incr)

# Create a datetime object
t = datetime.datetime.now() # 2017-12-05 01:29...

# Add minutes
t2 = add_minutes(t,5)

# Whenever you need to output use stftime:
print(t2.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Prints:

```
01:34
```

Comment: how can i make the t variable a string with the time given by me like this ("HH:MM")

Comment: @André Using strftime (see last line)

Comment: so t = t.strftime() ? i dont understand the sintax of datetime

Comment: @André sorry André but what you do is simly `t.strftime("%H:%M")` to get a string when you need it, you should never use `t = ` as that would overwrite the datetime and then you can't do more operations

Comment: but when i call the function, the t argument needs to be a string, like this for exemple add_minutes(“22:30”,5), but its not working

Comment: Try: `add_minutes(datetime.datetime.strptime("22:30","%H:%M"),5)`

Answer (score 0):

If you *aren't allowed* to use standard datetime library then you could at worst modify `add_minutes` so that:

```
your_return_string = hours + ':' + minutes

if get_minutes() < 10:
    your_return_string = hours + ':' + '0' + minutes

if get_hours() < 10:
    your_return_string = '0' + your_return_string
```